# how to fix http.post() request is not working on android oreo version

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using http post method to fetch server data, but the post is not working on android oreo version devices. any work arounds?

Is there any additional configurations or app permissions required ?

```
this.http.post('http://13.235.12.168:81/api/values/Login',JSON.stringify(body),{headers:headers})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data=>{
.users = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the issue. From pie version the api's without SSL will not work. To fix this there are two ways

1. Add exception for unsecured url in config file https://halflastbreath.blogspot.com/2019/06/my-network-requests-are-not-working-in.html
2. Enable SSL for your API

I done that the second one . Hope someone get help ...